# Ltablex doesn't break multirow

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow, ltablex

I built a multipage table containing multirows using the `ltablex` and `multirow` packages.
My question is, how can I now prevent Latex from breaking such a multirow?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm
        \captionsetup{type=table}
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|X|p{0.1\textwidth}|}
            \cline{1-5}
            \textbf{Direction} & \textbf{Signal Name} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}  \\\cline{1-5}
            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
        \end{tabularx}
        %\caption{Table Cap}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{center}
```

Comment: `\ltablex` change `X` column features. To restore it back, you need to add `\keepXColumns`. Please extend your code snippet to cmall but complete document, which we can compile as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now updated with an MWE to solve the missing line on page 2, and I assumed that you *do not* want repeating header.

Since you have not provided a working MWE, it is difficult to be more specific, so I give you some possible solutions.

Remember that a multirow is only an overlay over the cells underneath. Therefore, for [longtable](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable), which is use behind [ltablex](https://ctan.org/pkg/ltablex), each row underneath a multirow is a possible breaking point. Page 9 in the [longtable manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) describes different commands you may use either to force a page break before the `multirow`, or to avoid a page break between the said rows.

Remember that you also can use the LaTeX command `\enlargethispage{<val>}` to increase or decrease available space on a given page. For example:

```
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
```

may give room for an additional row. A negative value:

```
\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}
```

will decrease the available space, forcing a earlier page break.

To have rules at the top of the next page, you put the rule command in the table header:

```
\cline{1-5}\endfirsthead\cline{1-5}
```

Instead of `\cline{1-5}` you may use a simple `\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            vmargin=0.7in, hmargin=0.7in%
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{array, hhline, ltablex, tabularx, multirow, caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{footnotesize}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}%\aboverulesep = 0mm \belowrulesep = 0mm
        \captionsetup{type=table}
        \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|X|p{0.1\textwidth}|}

\caption{Table Cap}\\

\endfirsthead
\cline{1-5} % Or \hline
\endhead
\cline{1-5} % Or \hline

\textbf{Direction} & \textbf{Signal Name} & \textbf{Symbol} & \textbf{Description} & \textbf{Type}  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}
          in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

            in  & \multirow[t]{2}{\hsize}{ready signal} & ready-v1  & Some description & 1 \\ \cline{1-1} \cline{3-5}
            out & & ready-v2 & Some description & 1  \\\cline{1-5}

        \end{tabularx}
\end{footnotesize}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, I did it using pagebreak, altough I was hoping to find a more "Word"ish approach. Tables are still a weakness of Latex in my opinion. You might have an idea how I now can add the missing `\cline` on the new page?

Comment: @Humpawumpa You put the cline in the longtable header, before the table body, try to add the command   `\cline{1-5}\endhead` and `\cline{1-5}\endhead`. But since you spanne all five columns, why do you not use `\hline` instead? The documentation for ltablex is very rudimentary, so you have to look at longtable's manual. As Zako suggests, I too recommend the use of `xltabular` instead.

Answer (score 2):

From your code snippet is not clear, why you need `ltablex` package. If you really need long table with `tabularx` features, then I suggest you rather use `xltabular` package (which is combination `longtable` and `tabularx` package).

In case the you persist to use `ltablex` then, in case that you like to have `X` column (in any `tabularx` table) with the same features as in standard `tabularx`, you need to add `\keepXColumns` in the document preamble.

In your case, I would redesign your table as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\makegapedcells
    \caption{Table Cap}\label{tab:mytable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|p{0.1\linewidth}| l | X | c|}
            \cline{1-5}
\thead[b]{Direction} 
    &   \thead[b]{Signal\\ Name} 
                    &   \thead[b]{Symbol} 
                                        &   \thead[b]{Description} 
                                                            & \thead[b]{Type}           \\  \cline{1-5}
in  & \multirow{2.4}{=}{ready signal} 
                    & ready-v1          & Some description  & 1         \\ \cline{1-1}      \cline{3-5}
out &               & ready-v2          & Some description  & 1         \\  \cline{1-5}
in  & \multirow{2.4}{=}{ready signal}
                    & ready-v1          & Some description  & 1         \\ \cline{1-1}      \cline{3-5}
out &               & ready-v2          & Some description  & 1         \\  \cline{1-5}
in  & \multirow{2.4}{=}{ready signal}
                    & ready-v1          & Some description  & 1         \\ \cline{1-1}      \cline{3-5}
out &               & ready-v2          & Some description  & 1         \\  \cline{1-5}
in  & \multirow{2.4}{=}{ready signal}
                    & ready-v1          & Some description  & 1         \\ \cline{1-1}      \cline{3-5}
out &               & ready-v2          & Some description  & 1         \\  \cline{1-5}
        \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

In above table design I anticipated that in all columns except of second column, where you have `multirow`s' cells and fourth (with `X` type) column you will have only short one line text.